# Can't make tkinter checkbutton work normally when running as script

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I defined a tkinter checkbutton widget to create check boxes based on a user defined list and return a new list including the selected elements. It works as expected when I run it directly on IPython console (I use Spyder3 most of the time). It also works if I save the function as a Python script and call it as a module's function in Python console. However, if I run the script containing this function, it behaves weird that all the change of those check buttons will not reflect to the real value at all; all of the values are **False** no matter what items I selected. The followings are the code and example:

**CheckBox.py** :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import askyesno
import sys

def CheckBox(picks, *Args):
    class checkboxfromlist(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, picks):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            self.vars = []
            for pick in picks:
                var = tk.BooleanVar()
                chk = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=pick, variable=var, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
                chk.pack()
                self.vars.append(var)

        def state(self):
            return list(map((lambda var: var.get()), self.vars))

    class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self, picks, text):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self)
            self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
            self.title('Select desired download')
            self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.on_exit)
            self.l = tk.Label(self, text='Please select desired download {}'.format(text))
            self.l.pack()
            self.ChkBox = checkboxfromlist(self, picks)
            self.ChkBox.pack()
            self.Button = tk.Button(self, text='Ok', width=40, height=2, command=self.quit)
            self.Button.pack()
            # Make popup window at the centre
            self.update_idletasks()
            w = self.winfo_screenwidth()
            h = self.winfo_screenheight()
            size = tuple(int(_) for _ in self.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x'))
            x = w/2 - size[0]/2
            y = h/2 - size[1]/2
            self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (size + (x, y)))

        def on_exit(self):
        # When you click x to exit, this function is called
            if askyesno("Exit", "Do you want to quit the application?"):
                self.destroy()
                sys.exit(0)

    text = ' for '.join(Args)
    App = MainWindow(picks, text)
    App.mainloop()
    mask = App.ChkBox.state()
    App.destroy()
    selected = [item for index, item in enumerate(picks) if mask[index]]
    return selected
```

Here is the snapshot of the widget:
[widget screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FcSM.png)

These work:

1. Paste the code directly in IPython console then run
   **CheckBox(MyList, 'item')**
2. Input *Python* in terminal, then *import CheckBox*, run **CheckBox.CheckBox(MyList, 'item')**

These don't work:

Run as a script either in spyder, terminal, or double-click

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    CheckBox(MyList, 'item')
```

Run as a external module in a script in spyder, terminal, or
    double-click

```
import CheckBox
if __name__ == '__main__':
    CheckBox.CheckBox(MyList, 'item')
```

I tried using Python 3.5.2 on Ubuntu and 3.6.4 on Windows 10 and both of them gave me the same problem. I have spent whole day figuring out what was going on but with no luck. Any comment would be very much appreciated.

***Edit***:
I found that the widget works until I add the following code at the beginning of the main function:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
```

The reason I do so is because there will be some user prompt widget later during the process. Without *root.withdraw()*, there will be always a blank window on the screen. The effect of the above code last until I restart Spyder3; this means I can't make my code work again by simply delete the above code. Here's the snapshots of the program:

This works:
[Screenshot of Spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Ida.png)

As you can see, the print out list is exactly the items I selected (I run it once then run it again to take the snapshot of the widget).

This doesn't:
[Screenshot of Spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjS4b.png)

The print out list is empty no matter how I selected the items.

***PS***: **fuck_tk** is exactly the same as **CheckBox.py** I post above.

***Edit2***:
I found out that in order to make all the widget works without showing the blank main tkinter window, I need to make all of my tkinter messageboxes as individual functions as below:

```
def User_Confirm():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    answer = askquestion('test', 'tkinter sucks')
    root.destroy()
    return answer
```

However, this workaround sound very stupid to me. Is there any elegant way to hide the main tkinter window while not influence the functionality of my CheckBox widget?

Comment: By "doesn't work" do you mean that nothing gets printed? If so try `if __name__ == '__main__': print(CheckBox(MyList, 'item'))`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I used to add a print function there to test the output of the mask and the output list. When I run it as a script. all of the elements in 'mask' are 'False' so the output list contains nothing.

Comment: Your code works on my machine (Python 3.6 windows 7). Could you please be more specific as to what doesn't work mean?

Comment: Thanks! I found that root.withdraw() affect my code's functionality. Additional information is added.